How can AI tools support asset generation?
I'm a newbie in game development and looking for some advice from the community about getting game assets. I've been messing around with Luma and Meshy for making 3D models, and they've been surprisingly not bad. But I'm kind of torn on whether diving into AI tools would make things easier or just be more of a headache.
I want to quickly build my small game. How can AI productivity tools support asset generation? What do I need to know about using them in place of traditional development practices?

Recommendations itself are off topic

The title doesn't really reflect the problem you are describing in your post.

Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please note that this is a Q&A website, not a discussion forum. It is a good place to post specific questions with objective answers. It is not a good place to ask questions that ask for people's general experience or for product recommendations.

In the current state of AI generation tools they help best with creating placeholder art and assets.
It is difficult to get the tool to create a set of assets that have a coherent style. The best way to get assets that follow such a coherent style is to have a human make them (and pay them fairly for it).
The other difficulty is that AI generated work is not copyrightable, there must be a human author that actually did significant work on the actual output before the result becomes protected by copyright.

Nothing in this answer strikes me as wrong, but I feel it's worth mentioning copyright law varies based on jurisdiction, in many places the rules are still in flux & there are legal technicalities with respect to AI & copyright. The USCO has granted copyrights for works that incorporate AI elements including  visual artwork, though presently the protection offered has a lot more nuance than if it had been completely human generated.
